# Getting `GC overhead limit exceeded` issue when we ran with log level as 'DEBUG' in logback-test.xml

Tags: karate

Getting `GC overhead limit exceeded` issue when we ran with log level as 'DEBUG' in logback-test.xml

```
<karate.version>0.9.4</karate.version>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in 0.9.5 - please confirm.

Comment: after upgrading version as 0.9.5, getting same `GC overhead limit exceeded` error. please suggest if any other way to try

Comment: @Mr.Venkat find the test that has a large response payload (comment it out to confirm) then help us test the new changes to report verbosity: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#report-verbosity - you need to use the `develop` branch: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide